# deleting photos from device

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, backup, nexus-4

I see this when I go to delete from the *Photos* app

> "Deleting will remove the photos and videos on your device and also
>   any backups in your account"
>   "Cancel"/"Delete everywhere"

is there a way to delete from my device without deleting the backup on my Google+ account
Nexus 4 Android 4.4.4

Answer (score 2):

When using the *Photos* app it will do that for you.

If you use the *Gallery* app it will only manipulate the local images, therefore deleting the local ones. The *Gallery* app comes with Nexus 4.

Comment: "Photos" does allow deleting only local pics, but you have to navigate to the right place first, and that's not obvious. See linked duplicate question for more. Because of this ambiguity Gallery might be the less error prone route.

Answer (score 1):

You can download an app like Quickpic that is a local gallery viewer and delete only local copies that way. It's probably the easiest way. I have no idea why Google photos has no options to delete only the local copy, forgetting such an essential feature is such a google thing to do.

Comment: I tried that and it still manages to delete from google+

Comment: You tried it specifically with Quickpic? Or from photos? As slybloty said in his answer it shouldn't do that if you use the gallery app or another local picture app. Try this, download a file explorer like ES File Explorer and go to your DICM/camera folder and manually delete a photo from there. If it still gets removed from your online backup then there must be sync going on on your phone where it keeps the two offline and online the same, although I have no idea what could do that.